# How can multiple people contribute to resolving conflicts during a large DVCS rebase operation?

Tags: git, mercurial, dvcs, rebase

A rebase of a very long-lived topic branch can be quite painful and take hours or days of work for one person. How can a second (or third) person contribute to the rebasing effort? Is there some tool that can find independent conflicts that two people could work on independently?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

turn on rerere

```
git config --global rerere.enabled 1
git config --global rerere.autoupdate true
```

whenever you resolve a conflict, the resolution will be recorded. Now you have to share it:

Set up a symlink to the `.git/rr-cache` directory. Initialize that as a repository. Have the other devs do that.

Now you can share the resolutions across the team via this resolution repository.

here is more on rerere: http://progit.org/2010/03/08/rerere.html

You may also rethink your strategy of rebasing. Merging is a better option for certain situations.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I think that answers the question of how others can benefit from my rebasing work. But what I am asking is how multiple people can go about resolving conflicts _in parallel_. My team is bottlenecked by a very large rebase, but as it is, only one guy can work on it due to the serial nature of a rebase. I would like to find some way to help him out (without sitting in his office staring over his shoulder).

Comment: I would still turn on rerere, /merge/ the branch and resolve the conflicts. Ship him the rr-cache so he can resolve the conflicts he encounters when he is rebasing.